# Centimeter to Feet converter in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program to convert a given value in centimeters to both feet and inches. I wrote two functions; one function converts the value in centimeters to feet and passes the decimal part of that value to another function which converts that decimal number to inches. The code is shown below:

```python
import math

def feetConverter(number):
    tempInchValue, feetValue = math.modf(int(number) * 0.03281)
    inchConverter(tempInchValue) #calls the inch converter function
    return feetValue

def inchConverter(tempInchValue):
    finalInchValue = tempInchValue * 12
    return finalInchValue

print("Enter the height in centimeters: ")
centimeterValue = input()
print(feetConverter(centimeterValue))
```

The problem is that the program is not given the inches value - as if the inchConverter function is not being called. I would appreciate any corrections. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a function can only return one value, you're printing the return value of `feetConverter`, the return value of `inchConverter` is being ignored

```
def feetConverter(number):
    tempInchValue, feetValue = math.modf(int(number) * 0.03281)
    inchConverter(tempInchValue) #calls the inch converter function, and ignores the return value
    return feetValue # returns feetValue only.
```

you should call & print `inchConverter` separately:

```
print(inchConverter(centimeterValue))
```

alternatively, you could return a `tuple` of values:

```
def feetConverter(number):
    tempInchValue, feetValue = math.modf(int(number) * 0.03281)
    return (feetValue,inchConverter(tempInchValue))
```

Comment: A function can return only one value, but that value could be a `tuple`.

Comment: -1, While you're right that the OP is ignoring the return value of inchConverter, in python functions can return multiple values. OP could do return feetValue, inchValue

Comment: @mtrw a tuple is still a single value, but i accept the comment

Comment: and inchconverter should work on the feet value, not the centimetre value (as given)

Comment: As should be clear from the successful use of `math.modf` a Python function *can* return multiple values (yes, technically by returning a single `tuple`, but Python syntax allows you to skip the tuple packing and unpacking and use the values from the tuple directly).

Comment: Python doesn't skip the packing and unpacking (e.g. `x, y = y, x`). You just don't have the eyes to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Is that homework? Otherwise why don't you use a unit conversion package? For instance quantities feels nice:

```
>>> import quantities as pq
>>> distance = 3*pq.meter
>>> distance.units = 'feet'
>>> distance
array(9.842519685039369) * ft
>>> distance.units = 'm'
>>> distance
array(2.9999999999999996) * m
>>> distance.units = 'inches'
>>> distance
array(118.1102362204724) * in
```